# Newbie in Javascript - Using JSfiddle, missing semicolon but I don't fully understand where

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

Alright, so I'm creating a little amateur game using Javascript by using the confirm function, prompt, and if - else statements.
However, in my code, which you can find here: http://jsfiddle.net/ShiiFtyyMendoza/yFzxj/15/

```
 function codeAddress() {
     if (prompt('Have you played this game?') === 'no') {
         confirm('This game is like Zork!');
         prompt('Do you need a refresher?');
         if (prompt('Do you need a refresher?') === 'yes'); {
             confirm('All it is, is that you are given a scenario, in which you are also given actions. These actions lead you through a certain path and ending. Pick carefully!');
         }
     } else {
         confirm('Lets play then!');
     }
     //beginning of game
     confirm('Dazed and a little groggy, you realize that you are trapped on an island after a crash landing. Along with other children, you know itd be a best idea to go and keep everybody calm.');
     //stay calm.
     prompt('What are you planning to do? 1. Stay calm and keep everybody in check. or 2. Panic.');
     if (prompt('What are you planning to do? 1.Stay calm and keep everybody in check. or 2. Pacnic') === '1.'); { //this ends after line 19
         confirm('That seems like a great idea. You go around the island, doing your best to convince others to stay calm and keep their composure.');
         prompt('In the attempt to stay calm, you know that youve read about some situation like this - it was in Lord of the Flies, yes! That was it! With Piggy on your side as you walk the beach, you know you had to get an item to get peoples attention. What would you do? 1. Pick up a conch laying on the beach, or 2. Take Piggys glasses');
         if (prompt('In the attempt to stay calm, you know that youve read about some situation like this -  it was in Lord of the Flies, yes! That was it! With Piggy on your side as you walk the beach, you know you had to get an item to get peoples attention. What would you do? 1. Pick up a conch laying on the beach, or 2. Take Piggys glasses') === '1.'); {
             confirm('Yeah, that was probably the best idea. With the conch you could blow into it and end up being able to gather attention and create a leadership.');
         }
     } else {
         {
             confirm('That works too! The sunny day lets you focus the concentrated light onto wood and create a fire.');
             confirm('Soonly, as you wait, you see a helicopter from the horizon come and land. Oh what a miracle! Youve been saved!');
             confirm('Or so you thought');
             confirm('30 minutes into the flight, a dog fight occurs by your position, shooting your helicopter out of the sky, landing you onto another island, this time even farther than before.');
             confirm('Game over.');
         }
     } else {
         {
             confirm('Ahh... this isnt so good. Your commotion had instigated chaos and getting others to follow in your stead would be extremely challenging.');
             confirm('In the choice of panicing, every attempt to gather every or even anybody to keep composure, the group of boys fail to make ends meet. Slowly, as each day passes, you grow weak, only for you to realize that the choices that you had made was a catalyst of failure - causing death for others, and soon enough, you.');
         }
     }
 }
 window.onload = codeAddress;
```

I have an error in line 21 and 29 because of a missing semicolon. What am I doing wrong? I don't really know the complicity of JS, so I'm quite lost! 
Any help is appreciated!

---

**UPDATE**
Based on GitaarLAB's answer, I created the following code: http://jsfiddle.net/ShiiFtyyMendoza/yFzxj/24/

```
function codeAddress() {
var answer;
answer = prompt('Have you played this game?');
if (answer === 'no') {
    confirm('This game is like Zork!');
    answer = prompt('Do you need a refresher?')
    if (answer === 'yes') {
        confirm('All it is, is that you are given a scenario, ' + 'in which you are also given actions. ' + 'These actions lead you through a certain path ' + 'and ending. Pick carefully!');
    }
} else {
    {
        confirm('Lets play then!');
    }
}
//beginning of game
confirm('Dazed and a little groggy, you realize that you are ' + 'trapped on an island after a crash landing. \n' + 'Along with other children, you know it\'d be a best ' + 'idea to go and keep everybody calm.');
answer = prompt('What are you planning to do? \n' + '1. Stay calm and keep everybody in check, or \n' + '2. Panic.');
if (answer === '1') {
    {
        { //stay calm
            confirm('That seems like a great idea. \n' + 'You go around the island, doing your best to ' + 'convince others to stay calm and keep their composure.');
            answer = prompt('In the attempt to stay calm, you know that ' + 'youve read about some situation like this - ' + 'it was in Lord of the Flies, yes! That was it! \n' + 'With Piggy on your side as you walk the beach, ' + 'you know you had to get an item to get peoples ' + 'attention. \n\n' + 'What would you do? \n' + '1. Pick up a conch laying on the beach, or \n' + '2. Take Piggys glasses');
        }
        if (answer === '1') {
            {
                {
                    { //pick conch
                        confirm('Yeah, that was probably the best idea. \n' + 'With the conch you could blow into it and end ' + 'up being able to gather attention and create ' + 'a leadership.');
                        answer = prompt('With a tool to help gather attention,' + ' itd be a shame if you didnt put it to good use. \n' + ' Would you  1. try to preserve civilization on the island? \n' + ' or 2. go primitive, in an attempt to escape quickly');
                        if (answer === '1') { //establish leadership - to follower else
                            confirm('With the help of others,' + ' you were able to create multiple shelters' + '. By doing so, you were able to increase your chance of surviving.')
                            answer = prompt('With the comfort of having shelter, you are led into a disagreement with Jack.' + ' He, himself creates a separate group, weakining the once joint operation.' + 'you have a choice to fight back, in an attempt to be able to all go home together as one. \n' + 'What is your decision? 1. Stay calm and sleep in your newly made shelter \n' + 'or \n' + '2. Plan your escape with the others.');
                            if (answer === '1') { //sleep calmly
                                confirm('After your little disagreement, you decided to stay calm, and sleep instead of rising up and fighting.' + ' But as soon as you come out of your shelter, you realize that something is oh so very wrong.' + ' Nobody is here! Everybody else had been eloquently convinced by Jack to leave your intention for his.' + ' That worthless hunting group. He put the human primitive nature in front of priorities!');
                                answer = prompt('You do have a choice though. /n' + '1. Would you go lone wolf and work hard to save yourself? \n' + '2. or would you instead look for them? In the hopes of joining their league.');
                                if (answer === '2') //look for them
                                {
                                    {
                                        confirm('With the decision to walk around and try to find the group,' + ' you hear a chant - the hunting chant.' + ' They were close by...' + ' As you closed up, however, you were attacked by Roger and Jack.' + ' How weird. You dont remember any reason for hostility, until Sam and Eric came by.' + ' Hey! OVER HERE! said Sam and Eric \n' + ' As you came closer, their voices became fainter' + ' Run, they said. That was all they said.');
                                        confirm('You didnt think so at first, but the twins were right.' + ' As soon as you started to run, you were spotted by Jack.' + ' With a sadistic sense, he lit the forest they had all once occupied, on fire.');
                                        confirm('Closer and closer, you ran towards the shore,' + ' but it was a trap!' + ' There was no way out, they had lit the forest on fire to drag you out.');
                                        confirm('Life seems to flash before you, until you realize that a ship started to aproach.' + ' Out came the navy officer, and you were finally saved.');
                                        confirm('Good game!');
                                    }
                                } else { //fire signal - from if followers are gone
                                    confirm('You try to go lone wolf,' + ' in order to, you had created different signals to be seen.' + ' One, was a drawn message on the shore.');
                                    confirm('Another attempt was to set fire on to the forest.');
                                    confirm('This would have worked, however fights had not occured by your position, and you were never discovered.');
                                    confirm('Without any materials to create signals, and the death of many animals and other sources of food,' + ' you slowly perished.');
                                    confirm('Game over');
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            { //raft from followers, if from establish leadership
                                confirm('You in the end decide to leave it all, and to do so, you desperately thought of an option to use as an escape.')
                                confirm('With the others boys, you decided a plan.')
                                confirm('Going through the island, looking for stable pieces of wood, you decided to build a raft.')
                                confirm('What a great idea! Youll be able to go home!')
                                confirm('At least you hoped so.')
                                confirm('That same day, as you hopelessly rowed away from the island, a storm hits.')
                                confirm('With your lack of ability to swim for long periods of time, you fatigue and slowly drown to your death.')
                                confirm('It would have probably been better to stay with the other boys at the island.')
                                confirm('Game over.')
                            }
                        }
                    } else { //glasses
                        confirm('That works too! The sunny day lets you focus ' + 'the concentrated light onto wood and create a fire.');
                        confirm('Soonly, as you wait, you see a helicopter from ' + 'the horizon come and land. \n' + 'Oh what a miracle! Youve been saved!');
                        confirm('Or so you thought');
                        confirm('30 minutes into the flight, a dog fight occurs ' + 'by your position, shooting your helicopter out ' + 'of the sky, landing you onto another island, ' + 'this time even farther than before.');
                        confirm('Game over.');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        { //panic
            confirm('Ahh... this isnt so good. \n' + 'Your commotion had instigated chaos and getting ' + 'others to follow in your stead would be extremely ' + 'challenging.');
            confirm('In the choice of panicing, every attempt to gather ' + 'every or even anybody to keep composure, the group ' + 'of boys fail to make ends meet. \n' + 'Slowly, as each day passes, you grow weak, only ' + 'for you to realize that the choices that you had ' + 'made was a catalyst of failure - causing death for ' + 'others, and soon enough, you.');
        }
    }
}
window.onload = function () {
codeAddress();
};
```

What do you think?

Comment: sorry, the last part "}window.onload = codeAddress;" was left out from the block.

Comment: I restored your original question (otherwise all current answers would be useless, as we need to think about future readers to) and added your new code/question.

Answer (score 3):

For example:

```
if (prompt('What are you planning to do? 1.Stay calm and keep everybody in check. or 2. Pacnic') === '1.');
```

Simplified version:

```
if (condition);
```

If statements don't have semicolon at the end.
PS: You make the same mistake a few lines later.

Comment: In some cases, it does work - but only when the if - else statement is short, but for a longer one, what would be a solution? Because it won't run unless i find the area for the missing semicolon...
P.S.  I'm extremely sorry if it's obvious, haha...

Comment: Alright. In order for me to have fixed other errors on line 29 where } }else { { creates a commotion, I did remove semicolons from the statements. However it still persists at 29

Comment: it seams like we are having race-conditions here in the comments :)  what @FranciscoAfonso is saying is that you need to REMOVE the semi-colons after the `if statements` (you are not missing semi-colons in your code you have a few extra. and they break your code ).

Comment: Did that :) 
I'm only finding the last area.

Comment: Nope, the semicolons after if statement are still there. I really dont know how to explain with more detail. 
if(condition){} is right, but if(condition);{}  is not!

Comment: Yep. Removed the semicolons for the if statements. The last else is the only one preventing the code from running

Comment: @user2338028 are you still using http://jsfiddle.net/ShiiFtyyMendoza/yFzxj/15/ ??
Every single if statement have a semicolon at the end, and that is wrong. That's what im trying to explain here. Just REMOVE them, don't had things.

Comment: lines 5, 15 and 18, ifs with semicolons.

Comment: It's not /15 anymore, sorry! :O 
Got it. Thanks!

Comment: Well, that's because you're not really making anything.
You have two problems there. 
Ill update my answer so you can see them.

Comment: I meant to have it as if(true){} else - but each one whether true or false, would be another if statement

Comment: He needs invocation cause there's no html :P But yeah, it wasnt very correct so i deleted that part.

Comment: If you're still using the 16 version lines 28 and 32 have extra {} inside else

Comment: Well he should try with html but i dont even want to start more problems xD
@user2338028 now i think only thing left is what Josh said, you have consequent else statements.

Answer (score 0):

In your code there are a lot of errors.

Apart from everything Francisco Afonso pointed out in his answer, I'd like to add the following.

Your last line: `window.onload = codeAddress;`
In your fiddle you already had the 'onload' option selected (which already automatically wraps your javascript code).

You had dual blocks `{ statements here }` in your else-cases.

You `prompt`ed a question, then prompted the same question again in your `if` statement.

Now if I clean up some formatting and all errors, trying to stay as close to your code as possible, the result might look like this:

```
function codeAddress(){
    var answer;
    answer = prompt('Have you played this game?');
    if ( answer === 'no'){
        confirm('This game is like Zork!');
        answer = prompt('Do you need a refresher?')
        if (answer === 'yes'){
            confirm('All it is, is that you are given a scenario, '
                    +'in which you are also given actions. '
                    +'These actions lead you through a certain path '
                    +'and ending. Pick carefully!');
        } else {
        confirm('Lets play then!');
        }
    }

    //beginning of game
    confirm('Dazed and a little groggy, you realize that you are '
            +'trapped on an island after a crash landing. \n'
            +'Along with other children, you know it\'d be a best '
            +'idea to go and keep everybody calm.');
    answer = prompt('What are you planning to do? \n'
                   +'1. Stay calm and keep everybody in check, or \n'
                   +'2. Panic.');
    if ( answer === '1'){  //stay calm
        confirm('That seems like a great idea. \n'
                +'You go around the island, doing your best to '
                +'convince others to stay calm and keep their composure.');
        answer = prompt('In the attempt to stay calm, you know that '
                        +'youve read about some situation like this - '
                        +'it was in Lord of the Flies, yes! That was it! \n'
                        +'With Piggy on your side as you walk the beach, '
                        +'you know you had to get an item to get peoples '
                        +'attention. \n\n'
                        +'What would you do? \n'
                        +'1. Pick up a conch laying on the beach, or \n'
                        +'2. Take Piggys glasses');
        if ( answer === '1') {
            confirm('Yeah, that was probably the best idea. \n'
                    +'With the conch you could blow into it and end '
                    +'up being able to gather attention and create '
                    +'a leadership.');
        } else {
            confirm('That works too! The sunny day lets you focus '
                    +'the concentrated light onto wood and create a fire.');
            confirm('Soonly, as you wait, you see a helicopter from '
                    +'the horizon come and land. \n'
                    +'Oh what a miracle! Youve been saved!');
            confirm('Or so you thought');
            confirm('30 minutes into the flight, a dog fight occurs '
                    +'by your position, shooting your helicopter out '
                    +'of the sky, landing you onto another island, '
                    +'this time even farther than before.');
            confirm('Game over.');
        }
    } else {  //panic
        confirm('Ahh... this isnt so good. \n'
                +'Your commotion had instigated chaos and getting '
                +'others to follow in your stead would be extremely '
                +'challenging.');
        confirm('In the choice of panicing, every attempt to gather '
                +'every or even anybody to keep composure, the group '
                +'of boys fail to make ends meet. \n'
                +'Slowly, as each day passes, you grow weak, only '
                +'for you to realize that the choices that you had '
                +'made was a catalyst of failure - causing death for '
                +'others, and soon enough, you.');
    }
}

window.onload = function(){ codeAddress(); };
```

Working [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/yFzxj/20/).

One of the changes are that the string that a user types in the prompt-box is stored in the variable `answer` (which is locally scoped to the function `codeAddress`).
There are also some pointers in how you could make your code more readable and how to do new-lines in your message/prompt boxes.

The most important thing to note however is that if you look at your or my code, you can see that nesting and indenting of your story-line will become a hell!
So you should start to break things up in smaller parts of the story-line.
Also you'd want to have a array containing all pieces of text, so you don't need to type all the text inside your logic (and can translate your game later on).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Worked great! Thanks! Do you mind if you look over the code once more and pick out any problems?

Comment: SO is not meant for code-review. You might want to start using jshint (button in jsfiddle) or [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/) (better in my opinion): they will tell you about your mistakes. Also look at the error-console inside your browser!     As to your updated question: **(1)** the `+` in the strings were meant to make your code more readable, they are useless if you put everything on 1 line    **(2)** why did you (re-)add so many useless blocks (stuff between brackets `{ }`) (again)? They are (again) the reason why version 24 fails. Have another look at my answer!